# How do I iterate through a data frame and when I get a signal (+1 maX column) I select another cell from another column?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, iteration

I have created a basic panda data frame with historic USDJPY trading prices, moving averages and a final column 'maX' which decides if I BUY (+1), SELL (-1), or do nothing (0). As below;

```
             OPEN   HIGH    LOW   LAST     ma5     ma8    ma21  maX
Date                                                               
11/23/2009  88.84  89.19  88.58  88.97     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.0
11/24/2009  88.97  89.07  88.36  88.50     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.0
11/25/2009  88.50  88.63  87.22  87.35     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.0
11/26/2009  87.35  87.48  86.30  86.59     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.0
11/27/2009  86.59  87.02  84.83  86.53  87.588     NaN     NaN  0.0
11/30/2009  87.17  87.17  85.87  86.41  87.076     NaN     NaN  0.0
12/1/2009   86.41  87.53  86.17  86.68  86.712     NaN     NaN  0.0
12/2/2009   86.68  87.49  86.59  87.39  86.720  87.302     NaN  0.0
12/3/2009   87.39  88.48  87.32  88.26  87.054  87.214     NaN  0.0
12/4/2009   88.26  90.77  88.00  90.56  87.860  87.471     NaN  0.0
12/7/2009   90.27  90.47  89.04  89.51  88.480  87.741     NaN  0.0
12/8/2009   89.51  89.53  88.18  88.43  88.830  87.971     NaN  0.0
12/9/2009   88.43  88.69  87.37  87.87  88.926  88.139     NaN  0.0
12/10/2009  87.87  88.45  87.74  88.20  88.914  88.362     NaN  0.0
12/11/2009  88.20  89.81  88.20  89.10  88.622  88.665     NaN  0.0
12/14/2009  89.11  89.32  88.32  88.62  88.444  88.819     NaN  0.0
12/15/2009  88.62  89.95  88.58  89.61  88.680  88.988     NaN  0.0
12/16/2009  89.61  89.99  89.39  89.78  89.062  88.890     NaN  0.0
12/17/2009  89.78  90.37  89.56  89.97  89.416  88.947     NaN  0.0
12/18/2009  89.97  90.91  88.98  90.50  89.696  89.206     NaN  0.0
12/21/2009  90.45  91.24  90.16  91.17  90.206  89.619  88.571  0.0
12/22/2009  91.17  91.87  91.00  91.84  90.652  90.074  88.708  1.0
12/23/2009  91.84  91.87  91.32  91.64  91.024  90.391  88.858  1.0
```

How do I now iterate through the final column 'maX' so that if I get a new +1 buy signal (after a 0 or -1), I then select the following day's OPEN price and add this to a new column in the data frame on the right called 'Entry'. For a -1 or 0 in 'maX' the 'Entry' column would stipulate 0. I'm simply trying to create a new column 'Entry' on the dataframe that shows a buying level in 'Entry' column after the basic algo 'maX' changes to +1 (from 0 or -1).

My attempt below failed, i'm stuck on selecting the 'opening' level and adding it to a new 'Entry' column;

```
Buy = [0,]
maXLast = [0]
openLast = [0]
for maXCurr, openCurr in zip(maX[1:], 'OPEN'[1:]):
    if maXCurr == 1 and maXLast == 0:
        Buy.append(openCurr)
    elif maXCurr == 1 and maX == -1:
        Buy.append(openCurr)
    else:
        Buy.append(0)
    maXLast = maXCurr
    openLast = openCurr

Entry = pd.DataFrame(Buy,index = dfmas.index).astype('float') 
Entry.columns = ['Buy']
```

Many thanks in advance!